# Using zlib to estimate entropy rate of text data

Tags: stochastic-processes, natural-language, entropy

I'm trying to estimate the entropy rate of a text file (about 2 million characters, including spacing and punctuation). Calculating the entropy rate directly is not an option for me, for lack of computational power. Therefore, knowing that the entropy rate is a lower bound for the length of a lossless compressed sequence, I am trying to use the LZ77 algorithm to compress the text file with the `zlib` package in Python, and then calculate the entropy rate from there. Here's my Python implementation ("document.txt" is the text file):

```
import zlib

# Open the file you want to compress
with open("document.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()

# Compress the data using the LZ77 algorithm
compressed_data = zlib.compress(data.encode())

# Estimate the entropy rate
original_size = len(data)
compressed_size = len(compressed_data)
entropy_rate = compressed_size * 8 / original_size

print("Entropy rate:", entropy_rate)
```

However, I'm not sure that the results I get make sense. Can somebody confirm that what I'm doing makes sense or maybe point me in a better direction? Thank you very much!

---

EDIT: Following a suggestion from @whuber, I should clarify that what I want to do is to estimate the entropy of a certain stochastic series (in this case, a sequence of characters that make up a text) to evaluate how random/non-random it is. However, calculating $P(X_n|X_{(n-1)}, X_{(n-2)},..., X_1)$ does not seem feasible, so I'm trying to figure out how other people have used LZ algorithm to make an estimate.

Comment: If you have the computing power to compress the data, you should be able to compute an entropy even more easily.

Comment: Not really. I don't need to calculate the entropy, but the entropy rate, i.e. the limit of n that goes to infinity of the joint entropy of n words.

Comment: How to calculate a *limit* from a finite amount of data??

Comment: That's precisely my issue. I can't calculate the entropy rate directly, so I've been reading around that it's convenient to use lossless compression to estimate it, knowing that the entropy rate is a lower bound for the length of a lossless compressed sequence. However, I'm not sure how to go about it. For the moment, I'm looking at the compression ratio (length of the compressed data/length of the original data).

Comment: Compression won't get you any closer to infinity ;-).  It sounds like you want to *estimate* the entropy rate from this sample.  Now, no text file *per se* has an entropy rate, which is a property of a *stochastic process.*  Thus, you must be assuming something about this file that enables you to view it as realizing the beginning of some infinite process.  What can you tell us about these assumptions?  They might lead to some efficient ways to estimate the entropy rate.

Comment: I see, so I should probably rephrase it more correctly. What I want to do is to estimate the entropy of a certain stochastic series (in this case, a sequence of characters that make up a text) to evaluate how random/non-random it is. However, calculating P(X_n|X_(n-1), X_(n-2),..., X_1) does not seem feasible, so I'm trying to figure out how other people have used LZ algorithm to make an estimate.